# Facebook native login experience using Authorization Code flow (Redirected to the Facebook native App instead of the browser) - IdentityServer4

Tags: facebook, flutter, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, facebook-oauth

I am working on some OAuth 2.0 standards and non-standards flows to allow some clients to take the advantages of the SSO and give the users the native experience regarding the client that he/she working on.

One of the clients is a flutter App, so I followed the `Authorization Code Flow with PKCE`. The flow itself is a pretty straight forward to open a browser so you can exchange the code in this front channel with the access token through a backchannel. Things getting a bit complex while trying to authenticate via an external provider like Facebook. From the OAuth standard, it's easy to just pass the `&acr_values=idp:Facebook`.

The problem is when trying to follow the `Authorization Code Flow with PKCE` or even the old `implicit flow` to get access token through the Facebook, it opens the browser to ask you entering the Facebook username and password, but this is not the native experience as instead of that I want the web view to redirect the user to the app to authenticate via it instead of the browser like what's happening using the native Facebook SDK or Firebase SDK?

The only solution that I am following right now is following a non-standard authentication flow that I implemented myself to use the Flutter's Facebook SDK to get the Facebook token then exchange this token with my IdentityServer4 token after that ([described here](https://github.com/waqaskhan540/IdentityServerExternalAuth)) which seems very user-friendly experience but complex and at the same time not standard.

So, is it a way to use the `Authorization Code Flow with PKCE` to get the access token from the IdentityServer4 using Facebook as an external provider and use the Facebook app instead of the browser to authenticate so we can give the user a native experience and follow the best OAuth2.0 practices at the same time??